# Can't bind port in Google App Engine Launcher

Tags: wordpress, google-app-engine, localhost, port

When I try to deploy my app locally I can't get it running. This is what it's telling me:

```
2014-10-24 13:16:08 Running command: "['C:\\Python27\\python.exe', 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\google_appengine\\dev_appserver.py', '--skip_sdk_update_check=yes', '--port=3306', '--admin_port=8000', 'D:\\Documents\\Clever-CV Project\\wp39 - Copy']"
INFO     2014-10-24 13:16:15,315 devappserver2.py:733] Skipping SDK update check.
WARNING  2014-10-24 13:16:15,345 api_server.py:383] Could not initialize images API; you are likely missing the Python "PIL" module.
INFO     2014-10-24 13:16:15,368 api_server.py:171] Starting API server at: http://localhost:49717
INFO     2014-10-24 13:16:15,381 api_server.py:583] Applying all pending transactions and saving the datastore
INFO     2014-10-24 13:16:15,381 api_server.py:586] Saving search indexes
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\dev_appserver.py", line 82, in <module>
_run_file(__file__, globals())

<--ommitted-->>
raise BindError('Unable to bind %s:%s' % self.bind_addr)
google.appengine.tools.devappserver2.wsgi_server.BindError: Unable to bind localhost:3306
2014-10-24 13:16:15 (Process exited with code 1)
```

And I am a noob - so there's a very good chance I did something stupid, but I'm at my wits end and have found everything I could online to try.

- My SQL instance is running, the database passwords work and connect locally and to the remote app CloudSQL instance.
- My app.yaml file has a new version name
- the wordpress config file has the root names/passwords set-up correctly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue with running your app locally is in this part:  `'--port=3306'` which is mysql's default port and you said mysql is already running which means that port is already taken and cannot be used by your app. Instead of `3306` try the default `8080` port and increase it by one (i.e. `8081`, `8082`, etc) in case you need to run multiple applications at once.

Comment: Agh! That solved the first part. When I first installed MySQL, GAE Launcher, and Python there were certain things I didn't change unless the walkthrough told me to - updating the port number lets me Browse the project locally, but still can't deploy yet.